# Why java "delete" function is not removing text (.txt) file?

Tags: java, delete-file

I have a small java program that create & delete employee data.
I store employee data as .txt (text file). Everything is fine, but it fails to delete the text file.

**SIMPLE CLASS TO DELETE text file**

```
    public void removeFile(String ID)
    {

    File file = new File("file"+ID+".txt");
      if(file.exists())
       {
         if(file.delete());
         {
           System.out.println("\nEmployee has been removed Successfully");
         }
       }
      else
       {
            System.out.println("\nEmployee does not exists :( ");
       }
     }
```

I am getting message "Employee has been removed Successfully" but when I check the root folder, I can still see the file is still there (not deleted).

I tried and checked out different codes online /google, all shows no problem in delete () function.

Comment: Have you verified that the absolute path of `new File("file"+ID+".txt")` actually matches the path of the file you expect to be deleted?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel . I was trying to check absolute path by printing out it just after the "new file" line of above snippet.
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());. Nothing else , now files are getting deleted . No idea what happened , printing out absolute path made code work !!!!! thank you for your question.

Comment: try printing the absolute path before deleting

Comment: *"No idea what happened"* - My guess is that you ran the program in a different directory.   Read about how your operating system handles relative pathnames.

Comment: @StephenC literally I added the print then ran again, did not change any directory or moved any file.

Comment: Well ... literally (just) adding a print wouldn't change anything.  So something else must have happened.  Whether you realize or not.

Comment: Well I now see what you added.  And it was NOT just a print statement.  The problem is caused by that extraneous semicolon.  See the answer below.

Comment: semicolon is still there, but file is getting deleted, see the comment below- I don't know what changed, but I am only aware of only 1 change that being I added a print statement. BTW who closed the question, semicolon was not the problem. I ran it several times .

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it didn't delete the file (my guess would be you have a file of the same name in the project root, but you are wanting to delete one stored elsewhere) but there is a syntax error on the if statement:

```
if (file.delete());
```

You need to remove the semi-colon at the end of that line because that is terminating the if clause. The following `System.out` line is not conditional on `file.delete()` being true or false. It will be printed regardless.

See what outcome you get when removing the semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew B , but I am running my code successfully without removing semi colon. I mentioned above what i did (print our file location just below "new file". Did not changed location, file path. Its working well and deleting the correct files. I am clue less why printing out path did it. (Seems like somebody closed the question claiming it was semicolon. But it is not)

Comment: Your code will run fine with the semi-colon but it will **always** output "Employee has been deleted successfully" even when the delete fails. If you remove the semi-colon, it will only print that on success.